# How do you build a CMake target or not depending on an environment variable?

Tags: cmake, code-generation

I have a target which generates some code, however, I do not always want to generate the code, because it is time consuming, and causes lots of recompilation. I want to build like this:

```
NOGEN=true make
```

But CMake is thwarting me:

```
    add_custom_target(gen_messages
        if (NOT DEFINED ENV{NOGEN})
            COMMAND echo "Generating messages"
            COMMAND ...
            ...
        endif()
    )
```

It doesn't like it inside the custom target. I can't make out why. As usual, the `ìf` documentation does not explain. I am able to use it outside the target.

How do I do this?

Comment: "It doesn't like it inside the custom target. I can't make out why." - Because in CMake function calls cannot be nested. This is not specific for `if` command, this is about the whole CMake language. If you want to perform conditional operations inside COMMAND, you are better to write a script (in shell, python, etc.), which implements that logic, and run this script in COMMAND clause.

Comment: Depending on when you want the environment variable to be evaluated, you need to conditionally add the target, pass the value of the environment variable to a script (for evaluation at time of configuration) or create a cmake script containing the logic for evaluating the environment variable and run it via `... COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -P script.cmake` (for evaluation at the time of building the target).

Comment: I don't get it. This is exactly what CMake is for, but it can't do it?